# Use variable inside Observable<>

Tags: typescript

Normally I write a function like this `getAll(): Observable<WorkflowDtoPagedResultDto> {` where I add a class inside the `Observable<>` but I now I'm trying to see if I can make it more Dynamic: So my desired result is to use `Observable<this.target>`.

But I will not alow me to use this.target due to the dot (I believe).

I've tried to look into the use of eval or other ways to do it, but I felt short on find a solution, so maybe someone can point at the right direction.

*My GenaricServiceProxy.ts file*

```
@Injectable()
export class GenaricServiceProxy{
    private http: HttpClient;
    private baseUrl: string;
    protected jsonParseReviver: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined = undefined;
    private target: any;

    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient, @Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "";
    }

    public setData(target:any){
        this.target = target;
    }

    getAll(): Observable<WorkflowDtoPagedResultDto> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/services/app/Workflow/GetAll?";

        let options_: any = {
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Accept": "text/plain"
            })
        };

        return this.http.request("get", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_: any) => {
            return this.processGetAll(response_);
        })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
            if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
                try {
                    return this.processGetAll(<any>response_);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<WorkflowDtoPagedResultDto>><any>_observableThrow(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<WorkflowDtoPagedResultDto>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this.target has type any it wouldn't matter if you wrote `Observable<any>`. Or maybe define a type specifically for this.target  `type Target = ...`?

Comment: @uranshishko I use `setData` to return an object like WorkflowDtoPagedResultDto or another into this.target, so that is why it's set to `any`.

Comment: The problem is that `this.target` is not a valid type in the eyes of typescript which is why you can't use it like this `Observable<this.target>`. As I mentioned in my previous comment, the best way would be to define a custom type e.g `type Target = { [key?: string]: any }`, and then use it in `private target: Target` and  `Observable<Target>`. That is if you want to be more flexible.

Comment: @uranshishko Thanks for the info, One question: What is the point of using `private target: Target` if i dont use `target` anywhere?

Comment: @uranshishko I got it to work, if you want add an answer with your solution so others can get use of it.

Comment: As I don't know the whole context of your code I just assumed that you had some use for it in your code. If you don't have any use for that property you could just remove it, as well as the setData method. That being said, if you wish to be flexible with the type you just define your own e.g type `type t1 = { [key: string]: any } // object-like type with optional key and any value`, and then maybe `type t2 = /*some other type definition*/`. and then maybe a union of both to be even more flexible `type t3 = t1 | t2` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this.target` is not a valid type in the eyes of typescript which is why you can't use it like this `Observable<this.target>`. If you wish to be flexible with the type you just define your own e.g type `type t1 = { [key: string]: any } // object-like type with optional key and any value`, and then maybe `type t2 = // some other type definition`. and then maybe a union of both to be even more flexible `type t3 = t1 | t2` etc